# Scheduling Process with Semaphores Synchronization

Tags: operating-system, semaphore

Given that we have semaphore(<s>mutexes</s>) synchronization mechanism. Now, if we are given some processes to schedule as follows:

[image]

Also, given that four processes produce output using the routine `“printf”` and synchronize using three semaphores `“R”`, `“S”`  and `“T.”` **We assume `“printf”` won’t cause context switch**.

**Question**: my question is, given the previous information, I don't see any information how these processes get scheduled nor scheduling algorithm. We know that semaphores are in **kernel mode** and thus won't be preempted, but still my question is in what order should we run the processes and which one we should start with? Is it process `p_1`, `p_2` , `p_3` or `p_4` please?

**Edit**: I claimed they are mutexes, but it was not given.

Comment: 'semaphore (mutexes)' no.  The two are not equivalent.

Comment: 'what order should we run the processes' - on how many cores?

Comment: Do you have an example of an app where such info would be useful?  Sounds like an academic exercise with next-to-no real-world value.

Comment: @MartinJames. Thank you for your replies. Yep this is an academic question. The CPU is assumed to be multiprogramming, so we have one core that is able to run one processes at a time while other in RAM can be in I/O state. Again, I am just looking here please for the order by which these processes will be scheduled as this is not given and can not be deduced as I see. I am not sure if there is a strategy here?

Comment: @MartinJames. Hint: answer is 3 A's and `n` B's, where `n` means any.

Comment: @MartinJames. Here we have counting semaphores. So, we can get 3 A's, but why we can get any B's please given that `T=0` and so any process will be added in Queue and won't be able to proceed as there is no `Up(T)` anywhere before printing, so I don't think we can get any `B's`. What do you think please?